# Python JSON parsing does not find key or value I want

Tags: python, json, function, parsing, recursion

I have a code that recursively parses through a rather large JSON. I have recreated what I need with a small JSON here and the problem persists.

```
{
    "one": "one",
    "two": {
        "three": "three",
        "four": [{
            "five": {
                "six": "six"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

and here is my Python

```
json_file_path = r"\filepathto\testing.json"
j = json.load(c.open(json_file_path, 'r', 'utf-8-sig'))
def dict_opener(j):
    if isinstance(j, dict):
        for key, value in j.items():
            if isinstance(value, list):
                list_opener(j)
            if isinstance(value, dict) and key == "five":
                print("found")
            elif isinstance(value, dict):
                dict_opener(value)

def list_opener(j):
    for i in j:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            list_opener(i)
        elif isinstance(i, dict):
            dict_opener(i)


dict_opener(j)
```

This works to get many of the JSON elements (for instance, doing a key like `three` works fine), but doesn't work when I need the `five` element. Right now I'm just trying to get everything inside `five`, so I don't care how it's formatted or anything. I'm also aware that `j["two"]["four"][0]["five"]` works but the JSON will be constantly changing so I don't want to do that.

The function runs with no errors but gives no output (not even "found") so I don't know why it's happening. I'm pretty new with JSONs so maybe this is a stupid question but I can't seem to figure it out all the same.

Comment: What is the `j` in `dict_opener(j)`?

Comment: whoops, forgot to include loading the json sorry. I will add that

Comment: When `dict_opener()` gets down into the `{"six": "six"}` dictionary, there is no "five" key, so it does not print anything.

Comment: @JohnGordon That makes sense. Is there a way to get the things inside "five" by using just "five"? It seems like the final function should be printing "six" then since it's a string

Comment: `final()` is only called if the key is "five", which is not true in that case.

Comment: It seems like you should call `final()` if the value is neither a dict nor a list, without caring whether the key is specifically "five".

Comment: @JohnGordon is there a way to call a function or print something inside of "five" by using "five" then? Sorry its a lot of questions but I want to be able to get what's inside of "five" only using "five"

Comment: If you care about the key being "five", you should check that _before_ you check if the value is a dictionary.

Comment: @JohnGordon How would you check that without knowing it's a dict when it's the key of a dict?

Comment: I don't understand that question.  Let me phrase my comment another way.  If the current dictionary key is "five" **and** the value is a dictionary, what should the code do?

Comment: @JohnGordon right now I just want it to register that it's being found. Based on what you said I'm lets just focus on the opening functions and print if it's found. I have a code that checks if j is a dict, then if so iterates through key and value. I have the line `if isinstance(value, dict) and key == "five": print("found")` and that still doesn't work, giving no output but running fine. Sorry for so many question.

Comment: You'll have to update the question to show this new full code.  Otherwise I don't know exactly what you changed.

Comment: @JohnGordon done, sorry

Comment: `if isinstance(j, list)` I think this is a mistake -- it should be `if isinstance(value, list)`

Comment: @JohnGordon fixed that but still same issue

Comment: ... and of course `list_opener(j)` on the next line should be `list_opener(value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example traverses the data recursively and if key with name "five" is found, yields the value:

```py
import json


def get_key(o, key_name):
    if isinstance(o, dict):
        for k, v in o.items():
            if k == key_name:
                yield v
            else:
                yield from get_key(v, key_name)
    elif isinstance(o, list):
        for v in o:
            yield from get_key(v, key_name)


with open("data.json", "r") as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)


print(next(get_key(data, "five")))
```

Prints:

```
{'six': 'six'}
```